# Quisiera pintar una tabla con los valores del objeto inventario

Tags: javascript

soy bastante novato y no consigo resolver esta cuestión a pesar de haber invertido ya unas cuantas horas. Mi objetivo es pintar una tabla Quisiera pintarla en una tabla así preconfigurada, cuyas filas porincipales sean MARCA TIPO y CANTIDAD EN CAJAS para que a posteriori se muestre los valores del objeto en cada departamento anteriormente mencionado.

```javascript
const inventario = {
    barcelo: {
        cajas: 20,
        tipo: 'ron'
    },
    brugal: {
        cajas: 40,
        tipo: 'ron'
    },
    havana: {
        cajas: 25,
        tipo: 'ron'
    },
    tanqueray: {
        cajas: 26,
        tipo: 'gin'
    },
    seagrams: {
        cajas: 4,
        tipo: 'gin'
    },
    pIndias: {
        cajas: 17,
        tipo: 'gin'
    },
    jWalker: {
        cajas: 20,
        tipo: 'whiskey'
    },
    ballantines: {
        cajas: 22,
        tipo: 'whiskey'
    },
    wLabel: {
        cajas: 31,
        tipo: 'whiskey'
    },
    tBitch: {
        cajas: 12,
        tipo: 'shots'
    },
    tequila: {
        cajas: 14,
        tipo: 'shots'
    },
    jagger: {
        cajas: 18,
        tipo: 'shots'
    },
};
```

Mi intento va en esta dirección:

```javascript
let valoresXobjetos = Object.values(inventario)
let entries = Object.entries(inventario);

console.log(valoresXobjetos, valoresXentradas)
let cuerpoTabla = document.createElement('tbody');

console.log(document.getElementById('inventarioAlcohol').appendChild(cuerpoTabla))

function pintarTabla() {
    var tabla = document.createElement("table");
    var fila;
    var celda;
    for (var i = 0; i < persona.length; i++) {
        const fila = document.createElement("tr");
        const celda = document.createElement("td");
        celda.appendChild(document.createTextNode(persona[i].codigo));
        celda.appendChild(document.createTextNode(persona[i].nombre));
        celda.appendChild(document.createTextNode(persona[i].nombre));

        fila.appendChild(celda)
        tabla.appendChild(fila);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tabla);
}
valoresXentrada.forEach(valoresXobjetos => console.log(x[0], x[1].cajas, x[1].tipo))
```

Mi intento ha pasado por crear un array para poder extraer los atributos del objeto previo desde un array, sin embargo, tengo la sensación de que no se exactamente que hacer con eso. No es un trabajo de la universidad estoy practicando con un proyecto personal que yo mismo me he planteado.

Comment: Dónde está el intento que has realizado? https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874

Comment: @VFG. Aquí está.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

No voy a entrar en muchos temas tanto de la pregunta como de tu ¿intento?
Como sabrás, hay muchas formas de resolver los problemas. Pero una de ellas podría ser algo como lo que sigue. Creo que está escrito de una forma muy detallada para que puedas entender cada paso que se da.

Para esto, lo primero que hago es crear en el HTML un `<div>` con `id` `espacio-tabla` para meter en él la tabla.

Podría hacerse de otros modos más rápidos o simplificados, pero así creo que podrás entenderlo...

```
const inventario = {

    barcelo:{
        cajas:20,
        tipo: 'ron'
    },
    brugal:{
        cajas:40,
        tipo:'ron'
    },
    havana:{
        cajas:25,
        tipo:'ron'
    },


    tanqueray:{
        cajas:26,
        tipo:'gin'
    },
    seagrams:{
        cajas:4,
        tipo:'gin'
    },
    pIndias:{
        cajas:17,
        tipo:'gin'
    },


    jWalker:{
        cajas:20,
        tipo:'whiskey'
    },
    ballantines:{
        cajas:22,
        tipo:'whiskey'
    },
    wLabel:{
        cajas:31,
        tipo:'whiskey'
    },


    tBitch:{
        cajas:12,
        tipo:'shots'
    },
    tequila:{
        cajas:14,
        tipo:'shots'
    },
    jagger:{
        cajas:18,
        tipo:'shots'
    },        

};


var tabla = document.createElement("table"),
    encabezado = document.createElement("tr"),
    enc_titulo = document.createElement("th"),
    enc_tipo = document.createElement("th"),
    enc_cantidad = document.createElement("th");



enc_titulo.innerHTML = "Marca";
enc_tipo.innerHTML = "Tipo";
enc_cantidad.innerHTML = "Cantidad";
encabezado.appendChild(enc_titulo);
encabezado.appendChild(enc_tipo);
encabezado.appendChild(enc_cantidad);

tabla.appendChild(encabezado);

Object.entries(inventario).forEach(([clave,bebida]) => {
var fila = tabla.insertRow(),
    celda_titulo,
    celda_tipo,
    celda_cantidad;

celda_titulo = fila.insertCell();
celda_titulo.innerHTML = clave;

celda_tipo = fila.insertCell();
celda_tipo.innerHTML = bebida.tipo;

celda_cantidad = fila.insertCell();
celda_cantidad.innerHTML = bebida.cajas;

});

document.getElementById('espacio-tabla').appendChild(tabla);
```

Tienes un ejemplo funcionando en https://jsfiddle.net/sjezc0qw/

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de muchísima ayuda aunque finalmente y después de muchas horas lo resolví de la siguiente forma: 

let tabla =  document.getElementById(idTabla);
let cuerpoTabla = tabla.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));

entries.forEach( elementoDeEntries => {

let fila = document.createElement('tr');

fila.innerHTML = 
`   
<td>${elementoDeEntries[0]}</td> 
<td>${elementoDeEntries[1].tipo}</td>
<td>${elementoDeEntries[1].cajas}</td>
`;

cuerpoTabla.appendChild(fila);

});

};

pintarTabla('inventarioAlcohol');